# Cucumber 3: How to define a regular expression

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

In Cucumber 2 a regular expression is expressed as `(.*)` to get a parameter for the glue code. The [expressions documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/) of Cucumber 3 says that "You can use Regular Expressions or Cucumber Expressions." but sadly it does not mention the syntax.

In Cucumber 3 and 4 `()` expresses optional text and is equivalent to `(?:)` in Cucumber 2.

When `()` is reserved for optional text how can I define a regex in Cucumber 3? As `{.*}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cucumber 3 introduced Cucumber Expressions. For simple use cases they serve as a more readable regular expression. Unfortunately Java does not have a syntax to distinguish regular expressions from strings. So to distinguish between the two Cucumber JVM uses [a heuristic](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/blob/main/java/heuristics.adoc).

- `strings are cucumber expressions by default`
- `^definitely a regexp$`
- `/surely a regexp/`
- `this (.+) like a regexp`
- `this look(s) like a cukexp`

Adding `^` and end markers `$` is the surest way to get the regular expression behavior.