# cucumber escape char

Tags: regex, cucumber

I have to migrate a project to a new version of cucumber, I have adapted a lot of things, but now I'm facing an unexpected error.
When I try to execute anyfeature, cucumber complains because a step definition is not correct (was working fine previously).

ex :
Feature

```
Given I link signaal SIGNAL_1 with another signal SIGNAL_2
```

Step definition in error :

```
@Given("I link signaal (\\w+) with another signal (\\w+)")
    public void iLinkSignals(Reference signaalRef1, Reference signaalRef2){
        WerkInstructie signaal1 = signaalContext.getSignal(signaalRef1);
        WerkInstructie signaal2 = signaalContext.getSignal(signaalRef2);
        LinkedWerkInstructie linkedWerkInstructie = new LinkedWerkInstructie().withWerkInstructieId(signaal2.getId())
                .withWerkInstructieType(signaal2.getWIType());
        this.getRestAbstractWerkInstructieDriver().addLinkedWerkInstructie(SIGNAAL_RESOURCE_PATH, signaal1.getId(), linkedWerkInstructie);
    }
```

with the error :

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpressionException: This
> Cucumber Expression has a problem at column 18:
>
> I link signaal (\w+) with another signal (\w+)
> ^ Only the characters '{', '}', '(', ')', '', '/' and whitespace can be escaped. .

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?
I try multiple things without success.

Thanks in advance

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087604/5798435) states cucumber added something called cucumber expressions which are supposed to be an easier to read version of regex. You can see from the error it is trying to parse the string as a cucumber expression. The answer explains how to fix the problem.